# dynamically alter attributes of shape defined in xml?

Tags: android, xml

Currently using the following xml code as a background for a button in a program I am making. However, I would like to dynamically alter the background gradient within my code.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/buttonshape"
 android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient android:startColor="#F0F0F0" android:endColor="#A0A0A0"
  android:angle="270" android:id="@+id/buttonGradient"/>
 <corners  android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
  android:topRightRadius="7dp" />
</shape>
```

At first, I decided the xml should go, and I would just create my own class to handle this. However, I realized there was no good class to extend from. GradientDrawable doesn't have any apparent methods do round the corners. RoundRectShape doesn't have any method to give me a gradient. However, I also don't know of any accessors to gradients/corners within shapedrawable. I think what it comes down to is the fact that I don't understand exactly how this shape is being defined (I pulled it off an example used elsewhere). Every xml view that I define has all of its properties enclosed within the < /> tags. This is different. What are < gradient > and < corners >? I can't find them anywhere in the API/developer tools. And how can I dynamically alter them in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seth, you could try using the overloaded constructor of GradientDrawable:

```
public GradientDrawable (GradientDrawable.Orientation orientation, int[] colors)
```

This allows you to set the orientation of the gradient, and pass an array of colors of which the gradient will be supplied.
There is a method to set rounded corners:

```
public void setCornerRadius (float radius)
```

which you can perform on a GradientDrawable.

I offer this answer, though I have not yet gotten it to work myself :( Perhaps you'll have better luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a little [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/xpath_syntax.asp)..

By "dynamically" I don't know in what platform but in C# the below lines might guide you to your solution.

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load("path to xml file");
XmlNodeList gradientNodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//gradient");
foreach(XmlNode gradient in gradientNodeList){
    string startColor = gradient.Attributes["android:startColor"].Value; //GET
    gradient.Attributes["android:startColor"].Value = "#FFF"; //SET Custom Value
}
//OR Simply 
XmlNode xn = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/shape/gradient"); //and same as above
```

Or, You could use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) to **transform** your input xml to the desired format.

Comment: this android programming (java)

Comment: @Seth: Well, I'm sure something similar can be applied. I've already mentioned this was just as a hint of what could be done and NOT the end solution.

Comment: You won't be able to use Xpath; on Android, the xml resource files are compiled into bytecode, so modifying them after (even if there _is_ an xml file packaged) would have no effect unfortunately.